# how to get link My Cart and Check out in top.links in magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, toplinks

i want get link My cart and check out to top.links. any help?

and i tried get  language in top.links
  `<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>` in `header.panel`.
 But not success. how do get it?

Many thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your custom theme `app/desing/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` file.

```
 <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Cart</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="my-link1">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Checkout</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>                   
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: thanks @Rakesh it work good. i want get language. how do made it?

Comment: at which place have you required language?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, Can you help me on how to use toplinks sign in instead of sign in popup when we click on proceed to check out ?